# Tikzdevice with ggplot: overfull hbox

Tags: floats, captions, r, tikzdevice

I have the following `R` code to generate a `tikzdevice` plot:

```
tikz(file = "plot_CIs.tex", width = 5, height = 5)
par(cex = 0.8)
ggplot(confidence_interval, aes(x = Statistic, y = Values, group = 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, aes(ymin = Lower_Bound, ymax = Upper_Bound)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3, fill = "white") +
  labs(title = title, subtitle = subtitle) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

In `latex` I then use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
%The package tikz is available in pgf
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  %Do not try to scale figure in .tex or you loose font size consistency
      \centering
  %The code to input the plot is extremely simple
  \input{../plot_CIs.tex}
  %Captions and Labels can be used since this is a figure environment
  \caption{Sample output from tikzDevice}
  \label{plot:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which results in this image (in a `latex` pdf):
[image: tikzout]

I receive the following warning when compiling the `latex` document:

`Overfull \hbox (16.35pt too wide)`

which according the the log is related to:

```
(../plot_CIs.tex)
Overfull \hbox (16.35pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--14
```

How do I fix this warning? If I were using `\includegraphics` for my image, I would simply do:

`includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{plot_CIs.tx}`

Is there a way to do the same using `\input` for `tikzdevice` plots?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Tex S.E.! Please split your two questions in two separate posts.

Comment: Done: subquestion here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461636/tikzdevice-with-ggplot-centering-a-caption

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\resizebox` like this:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{../plot_CIs.tex}}
```

Untested since you do not provide a minimal *and* complete example.

Alternatively you could adjust the `width` argument in the `tikz(...)` call.